# Как получить список всех токенов на балансе пользователя по адресу?

Tags: криптовалюта, блокчейн

Например я использую [документацию bscscan api](https://docs.bscscan.com). В общем я могу получать транзакции с блок-чейна определенного пользователя по адресу. Но не могу получить список токенов по определенному адресу. *Я как понимаю мне надо прокручивать все транзакции пользователя и отслеживать поток. Куда он переводит, получат ли определенный токен, или отдает, и так составлять список токенов?* Если это так, но мне надо обработать большое количество транзакций. Возможно ли обойтись без этого?